# Customize the text-align, so it is a bit to the left

Tags: text, alignment

I want to have my text a bit to the left, so it is not centered but also not completely to the left.
Anyone know's how to customize the text align?

Comment: Can you share your code and what you have tried?

Will help with the answer. "A trick is to use an invisible space that will not collapse and make the font-family:monospace: "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the CSS `padding-left` property.

Depending on the exact effect you're looking for/situation you're in, you might also try `margin-left`, or simply `left`. Example:

```css
.myClass {
   padding-left: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   left: 10px;

}
```